# Managing loads of small projects

Tags: project-management, agile, project

most of the books about Project Management (if not all of them) describe management of one big project. Sometimes they describe how to manage very few projects in the same time. But I have very different situation.

I manage small team (4 people) with very small projects. Usually one engineer works on dedicated project. Some times One engineer work on few projects with different priorities (projects quite often switched to "on hold" state for a several days).

So my specific is:

- Small projects with short lifetime (1 week to 2 month in general)
- Projects usually are not shared between engineers
- Number of projects can be 2-3 times higher then number of people (some projects go "on hold" quite often)
- There are 2 longterm projects with lowest priority which can be shared between engineers

Can someone share own experience how to manage projects like this, or if you never had such experience but have an idea how to organize that I'll be glad to read it. 
Of course if you know book which can help me - I'll be glad to check it as well.

May be there is ready methodology for thas kind of projects which I never heard.

Thank you.

Comment: Finally found very good case study in "Scrum and Kanban: Making the Most of Both" (http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/01/kanban-scrum-minibook"). This case study is almost like my situation (a lot of customer support projects + 2 low priority big projects) but with bigger team. So I think I can tailor it for my case easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest looking at Kanban.  Here's some links to explore:

[Kanban (the book) on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0984521402)

[David Anderson's site](http://agilemanagement.net/)

[Some Kanban info on InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/kanban-for-software)

[The Limited Work In Progress Society](http://www.limitedwipsociety.org/)

Comment: Thanks, looks like Kanban can be very good solution for me.

Answer (score 3):

I have a team with this situation. My solution is to run each project with week long iterations and allocate an engineer to that project for a number of weeks, where possible. That way each project is only an average of half a week from being worked on if needed.

If you have higher levels of concurrency an alternative strategy would be to keep the short iterations and to set objectives for each iteration that include aspects of each project that requires attention. Multiple, concurrent burndown charts could be maintained to track the work for each project, but I would suggest these are a little academic if you aren't going to have effort expended on each project at a consistent rate. Using this approach would be unorthodox but would give you quick feedback, regular delivery of working software and progress on all the projects that need it so shouldn't rile the agile evangelists.

Comment: I also recommend limiting each engineer to one project per day (ideally, one per full week), so they don't lose extra time to switching focus between them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're stuck with this setup, the other responses give some reasonable ideas for dealing with it.

But this is a bad setup, and I'd advocate trying to change the situation.  You have too many simultaneous projects, and a work process that doesn't allow teamwork.

If multiple projects have the same stakeholders, try to get the business to merge the projects.  If this can't be done, or if it still results in multiple simultaneous projects, try to get the projects to be prioritized by business value so that you can *put the whole team on the most important project*, finish and deliver it and then move on to the next most important.

This will almost certainly involve getting people outside your team to make some difficult choices, and may be politically difficult, but there are gains for the business, which might help you with selling the change.

Getting a project out the door and in production more quickly will improve the cash-flow/throughput  of your company.  See [throughput accounting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throughput_accounting).

Putting the whole team on this one project will reduce the impact of a developer absence (see [bus number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_number)) and will mean your team is actually working as a team rather than as a bunch of individuals who happen to have the same manager.

If you can't get the business to prioritize down to one project at a time, by all means try for two, but with a team of only four developers, you should be doing one.

Comment: Thanks Don, but I think I stuck with this setup because of tasks type. Yes, there is almost no teamwork because of the task size. Basically I have more like customer support team dealing with some customizations of our software for customers. Customizations in most of the time are quite small and work on the same task couldn't be split between several engineers.